# What's wrong with this JAVA(jsp) code?

Tags: java, jsp

What is wrong with this code? When I run it I see an error.

```java
            int number=28; 
            int[] nums = new int[number];
            int cont=0;
            for(int i=0; i<=number; i++)
            {
                if(number%i==0)
                {
                    nums[i] = i;
                    cont++;
                }//if         
            }//for
```

Comment: you probably wanted your for loop condition to be `i < number`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

- Your for loop as below should start with 1 as dividing any integer from 0 will result in ArithmetricsException.
- Once you fix that, You are going to get ArrayIndexOutOfBound  exception as you are using <= in for loop hence if you try to access nums[i] when i = number, it will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception

  for(int i=0; i<=number; i++)

So your for loop should be like:

```
for(int i=1; i<=number; i++)
{
    if(number%i==0)
    {
        nums[i-1] = i-1;
        cont++;
    }//if         
}//for
```